# Phantomjs can't render/navigate to webpage intermittently in Jenkins

Tags: ruby, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, capybara

I am using (Phantomjs -v: 1.9.8) and cucumber-ruby-capybara Framework.Recently i saw some wired issue in Jenkins. Once in a while Phantomjs can't render my logon url and it throws below error:

```
unexpected response, code=404, content-type="text/plain"
Variable Resource Not Found - {"headers":    
{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,
identity;q=0.3","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"18",
"Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8",
"Host":"127.0.0.1:8910","User-Agent":"Ruby"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST",
"post":"{\"type\":\"browser\"}",
"url":"/session/c9asdf6b0-cr62-g1e5-a4c1-c58werebf0/log","urlParsed":
{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"log","directory":
"/session/c95fc6b0-cf62-11e5-a4c1-c5870519ebf0/",
"path":"/session/c95fc6b0-cf62-11e5-a4c1-c587asddasbf0/log","relative":
"/session/c95fc6b0-cf62-11e5-a4c1-c5870asdasebf0/log","port":"","host":"",
"password":"","user":"",
"userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/session/************/log",
"queryKey":{},"chunks":
["session","c95fc6b0-cf62-11e5-a4c1-c5870519ebf0","log"]}} 
(Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)
```

Failure Screenshot, i am getting is a blank black image with a small rectangular grey box in it.

Comment: 404 comes from the server, it doesn't show a rendering problem. Can you confirm the 404 in your server logs and check that the request URL was correct?

Comment: 404 comes from the server. But if i rerun the build, it passes afterwards. My url is correct. So every 10 builds, 1 fail for 404 error. But rerun the build, make that pass.

Comment: Even worse: variability is your arch-enemy. You really *have* to diagnose from server-side first. Once you've satisfied yourself server is working fine, then you can focus on client.

Comment: Upgrade to phantomjs 2.1.x  -- 1.9.8 is pretty buggy and really doesn't compare to a modern browser very well at this point in time

Comment: Go for it, though in 2 years sustained use I've never seen 1.9.x show spurious 404 errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with restarting phantomjs in case of this error and try again, Method to restart phantomjs is shown below

```
def restart_phantomjs
        session_pool = Capybara.send('session_pool')
        session_pool.each do |mode,session|
          driver = session.driver
            driver.restart
          end
        end
      end
      module_function :restart_phantomjs
 end
```

Comment: This might work, but is obviously a workaround rather than a solution. If "just restarting" fixes the problem that pretty much shows it's a timing issue, or perhaps a deployment issue.